Pentaho Data Integration treating empty string as null, "KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL=Y" doesn't work
My Pentaho Data Integration version is 10.2
input table
SELECT * FROM DGKHZZXXB WHERE QUAL_CERT_NM IS NOT NULL

I have filtered QUAL_CERT_NM column is not NULL, and there are some records have empty string value table
0000000000000000001 0023112186  128881230                                   组织机构代码
0000000000000000004 0023112186  128881230                                   组织机构代码
000000003           0026279604  912308286774694927                          统一社会信用代码
000000006           0027897510  SC10123082803169                            食品生产许可证
000000007           0027897510  黑H03300800                              粮食收购许可证
0000000000000000003 0028260802  230111100018269                             
0000000000000000005 0028338679  00183873-7                                  组织机构代码
000000004           0034323057  91231221325907508M                          统一社会信用代码证
000000001           0035003248  QS230609014029                              全国工业产品生产许可证
000000002           0035172856  QS230606010765                              全国工业产品生产许可证
000000005           0042147608  91231090MA1B8KUD45                          营业执照
000000008           0043830911  2310840000410414                            中征码
000000009           0043831455  912311815698736902                          营业执照
0000000000000000002 0043831455  912311815698736902    

In output tablet, QUAL_CERT_NM column cannot be NULL, and Pentahon treating empty string as null by default,
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - Error inserting row into table [CIF_CORP_QUAL] with values: [0000000000000000003], [0028260802], [230111100018269                         ], [], [null], [], [null], [null], [], [null], [15057], [15057], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [null], [X]
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - 
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - Error inserting/updating row
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - (conn=3221642291) ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into '(QUAL_CERT_NM)'
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - 
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - 
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:371)
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:112)
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:54)
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 -   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - Error inserting/updating row
2024-12-11 16:23:05.854 - 表输出.5 - (conn=3221642291) ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into '(QUAL_CERT_NM)'

I set kettle.properties
KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL=Y

and restart PDI, but it doesn't work,
I have tried v8.2 and v9.4, and neither worked.
I want to insert an empty string if the original value is empty, make "KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL=Y" works
